# Rails request parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working on a Rails `4.1` app with Devise `3.2.4`.

I'm stubbing a mobile API workflow, and I just noticed something weird.

If I submit this `POST` to the users controller (here I'm simplifying the URLs):

```
POST    /api/mobile_sign_in.json

body (json):
{
    "email" : "test@example.com",
    "password" : "foobar"
}
```

Rails creates this parameters hash:

```
{ "email"    => "test@example.com",
  "password" => "foobar",
  "user"     => {
    "email" => "test@example.com"
  }
}
```

That is, it adds a new member `user: { email: "string" }` to the parameters.

---

Something similar happens if I send an empty json object:

```
POST    /api/mobile_sign_in.json

body (json):
{}
```

which causes Rails to create this parameters hash:

```
{ "user" => {} }
```

---

If a send a *truly* empty body, the parameters hash is correctly empty.

I'm **not** using strong parameters for this function (yet).

---

#### Update

I can confirm that this happens in other controllers too.

For example, in the `LocationsController < ApplicationController`, rails is automatically grouping (and replicating) those attributes that can be mapped to the record.

```
{ "authentication_token" => "blablablablabla",
  "title"                => "test title",
  "body"                 => "one two three",
  "latitude"             => "0.0",
  "longitude"            => "0.0",
  "timestamp"            => "2014-04-16T16:28:20.441+01:00",
  "user_id"              => "1",
  "journey_id"           => "1",
  "location" => {
    "title" => "test title",
    "body" => "one two three",
    "latitude" => "0.0",
    "longitude" => "0.0",
    "timestamp" => "2014-04-16T16:28:20.441+01:00"
  }
}
```

In this case, the `"location" => {}` hash is added automatically.
I'm not yet using strong parameters, and I'm just experimenting with a test tool.

This controller is *devise-free*.

Comment: Can you post the code of your `mobile_sign_in` action?

Comment: It doesn't do anything funny. It finds the `User` using `params[:email]`, and then uses a Devise method to verify the password. If correct it returns the user record, otherwise it returns false. It does not manipulate the `params` object.

Comment: Added more info to the question

Comment: it usually happens because of invalid HTML code.

Comment: @ParitoshPiplewar could be... but it's not a HTML form submission. I'm using curl and another test tool, that just submits HTTP requests. No HTML involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails does this automatically for JSON requests to allow for easy access of the model.
It can be turned off by adding the `wrap_parameters false` block to a controller.

```
MyController < ApplicationController
  wrap_parameters false
end
```

For more info,
[ActionController::ParamsWrapper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html)

Comment: Right, thanks! I had completely forgot about that function of wrap_parameters, and I thought it only affected ActiveRecord's `to_json` stuff. Now that I know about it, it's actually quite useful.